# Checkbox setstate using java applet

Tags: java, windows, macos, applet, japplet

I am running old java applet code on mac.
In this code I am having around 15 checkboxes checking state in for loop and if state is true I am setting that to false. Which is triggering handle event of checkbox again and loop continues to infinity. THis is the problem in mac only, it is perfectly working in windows.

Comment: Not sure why your using a for loop to check states, why aren't you using events for when a box is checked/unchecked instead? Also, what is your question?

Comment: on each check box state I need to check state of every other check boxes and if condition matches then have to change state of certain checkbooks to true and other to false. So I am using loop and in mac on changing state of check box (using setstate) it is triggering event handler .

Answer (score 0):

Before you start you loop, try setting an "ignore" flag to `true`.  While it's `true` you should simply skip checking the loop.

Process the list as normal and when you finish, set the "ignore" flag to `false`...

```
if (!ignore) {
    ignore = false;
    try { 
        // Change state here and have fun
    } finally {
        ignore = false;
    }
}
```